# Win32 programming can not include template header file

Tags: templates, winapi

I am writing a standard Win32 windows UI program with Visual Studio 2017. But when I tried to include the following header file to the MyMainWin.cpp file (where you define windows and message handling), it complained many syntax errors. For example, it complained "unexpected token(s) preceding';'" for the line at the end of the class definition "};" If I included the following header file to a console application main.cpp, it worked fine. Why?

```
#ifndef _MY_RAND_H_
#define _MY_RAND_H_

#include <random>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

namespace myown {

void srand(int seed);
int rand();

template<class IntType = int>
class my_uniform_int_distribution {
public:
// types
typedef IntType result_type;
typedef std::pair<int, int> param_type;

// constructors and reset functions
explicit my_uniform_int_distribution(IntType a = 0, IntType b = std::numeric_limits<IntType>::max());
explicit my_uniform_int_distribution(const param_type& parm);
void reset();

// generating functions
template<class URNG>
result_type operator()(URNG& g);
template<class URNG>
result_type operator()(URNG& g, const param_type& parm);

// property functions
result_type a() const;
result_type b() const;
param_type param() const;
void param(const param_type& parm);
result_type min() const;
result_type max() const;

private:
typedef typename std::make_unsigned<IntType>::type diff_type;

IntType lower;
IntType upper;
}; //visual studio compiler complains "unexpected token(s) preceding';'" here

//method definition...
}
#endif
```

Comment: You don't have a closing } for the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably experiencing problems because your usage of `std::numeric_limits<IntType>::max()`. `windows.h` ends up including a file `minwindef.h`, which defines the unfortunate macros `max` and `min`. Snippet from `minwindef.h`:

```
#ifndef NOMINMAX

#ifndef max
#define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#ifndef min
#define min(a,b)            (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#endif  /* NOMINMAX */
```

If `windows.h` is included before your custom header, then the `std::numeric_limits<IntType>::max()` expression will get expanded to `std::numeric_limits<IntType>::((() > ()) ? () : ())`, which is invalid syntax.

There are two possible solutions:

- `#define NOMINMAX` prior to including `windows.h` - this is a good practice in general, since these `min`/`max` macros (and their non-windows forms `MIN` and `MAX`) are a known cause of issues
- include your custom header before `windows.h` - this isn't the best approach because it requires users of your custom header to have some additional knowledge

Comment: The first solution indeed fixed my problem. Your help is greatly appreciated.